# need help to install rvm on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm, ubuntu-10.04

I followed the instruction on this tutorial. 
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/21/set-up-an-ubuntu-local-development-machine-for-ruby-on-rails/

I got stuck on installing RVM.

```
$ bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
$ cd
$ nano .bashrc
$ [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
$ source .bashrc
$ type rvm | head -1
```

error message: bash: type: rvm: not found

i went back check line by line, found out that .rvm folder never get created.  I use the same tutorial on another ubuntu box, have no problem at all. coudlnt figure out what I did wrong this time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

as per the [rvm documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/#explained). Good luck